# How can I get constant value val accuracy and val loss in keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, mlp

I'm newbie in neural network and I try to do mlp text classification using keras. everytime I run the code, it get different val loss and and val accuracy. Val loss is increase and val accuarcy is decrease everytime I re-run it. The code that I'm using is like this:

```
#Split data training and testing (80:20)
Train_X2, Test_X2, Train_Y2, Test_Y2 = model_selection.train_test_split(dataset['review'],dataset['sentiment'],test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

Encoder = LabelEncoder()

Train_Y2 = Encoder.fit_transform(Train_Y2)
Test_Y2 = Encoder.fit_transform(Test_Y2)

Tfidf_vect2 = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=None)
Tfidf_vect2.fit(dataset['review'])
Train_X2_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect2.transform(Train_X2)
Test_X2_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect2.transform(Test_X2)

#Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim= 1148, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
opt = Adam (learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
    
from keras.backend import clear_session
clear_session()
    
es = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss",mode='min',patience=10)
history = model.fit(arr_Train_X2_Tfidf, Train_Y2, epochs=100,verbose=1, validation_split=0.2,validation_data=(arr_Test_X2_Tfidf, Test_Y2), batch_size=32, callbacks =[es])
```

I try using `clear_session()` to make the model not start off with the computed weights from the previous training. But it still get difference value. How to fix it? thank you

Comment: Full code please

Comment: @mujjiga with pleasure. I already add the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
How can I get constant value val accuracy and val loss in keras
```

I guess what you want is reproducible train runs. For that you will have to **seed the random number generator**. Getting reproducible result with seed is tricky on the GPU because some operations on GPU are non deterministic. However, with the model architecture you are using it is not a problem.

```
make model not start off with the computed weights from the previous training.
```

It is not the case, you are creating the model every time and the Dense layers you are using gets initialised from `glorot_uniform` distributions.

#### Sample:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras import callbacks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os
import numpy as np
import random as rn
import random as python_random

def seed():  
  os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
  os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""
  np.random.seed(123)
  python_random.seed(123)
  tf.random.set_seed(1234)


def train(set_seed):
  if set_seed:
    seed()

  dataset = {
      'review': [
          'This is the first document.',
          'This document is the second document.',
          'And this is the third one.',
          'Is this the first document?',
      ],
      'sentiment': [0,1,0,1]
  }

  Train_X2, Test_X2, Train_Y2, Test_Y2 = train_test_split(
      dataset['review'],dataset['sentiment'],test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

  Encoder = LabelEncoder()

  Train_Y2 = Encoder.fit_transform(Train_Y2)
  Test_Y2 = Encoder.fit_transform(Test_Y2)

  Tfidf_vect2 = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=None)
  Tfidf_vect2.fit(dataset['review'])
  Train_X2_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect2.transform(Train_X2).toarray()
  Test_X2_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect2.transform(Test_X2).toarray()

  #Model
  model = keras.Sequential()
  model.add(layers.Dense(100, input_dim= 9, activation='sigmoid'))
  model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
  opt = optimizers.Adam (learning_rate=0.01)
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
  #model.summary()
    
  history = model.fit(Train_X2_Tfidf, Train_Y2, epochs=10,verbose=0, 
                      validation_data=(Test_X2_Tfidf, Test_Y2), batch_size=32)
  return history


def run(set_seed=False):
  plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
  for i in range(5):
    history = train(set_seed)
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label=f"{i+1}")
    plt.legend()
    plt.title("With Seed" if set_seed else "Wihout Seed")


run()
run(True)
```

Outout:

[image]
[image]

You can see how the `val_loss` is different without seed (as it depends on the initial value of Dense layer and other places where random number generation is used) and how the `val_loss` is exactly the same with seed which make sure the initial values of Dense layers you are using are same between runs (and at other places where random number generation is used).

Answer (score 0):

During the training process, several different sources of randomness exist. You would need to eliminate all of those to get perfectly reproducible results. Here are a few of those:

1. The random weight and bias initialization leads to different training runs each time.
2. During training mini batching is used which influences the trajectory of the training process differently each time. Each training process that uses Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) as an optimization technique will thus observe a different ordering of inputs.
3. Randomness induced by regularization techniques such as Dropout.

Some of those sources of randomness can be overcome by setting a fixed seed, how this is done is described in [this older question](https://proceedings.mlsys.org/paper/2022/file/757b505cfd34c64c85ca5b5690ee5293-Paper.pdf).
This [paper](https://proceedings.mlsys.org/paper/2022/file/757b505cfd34c64c85ca5b5690ee5293-Paper.pdf) names several other possible sources of bias (such as data augmentation or hardware differences).

Comment: thank you for your reply, if i can ask again how to apply it in my code?